# How to find the cheaper product

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm learning sql and I stuck in a problem.
I have have three tables

```sql
table Product(
  model varchar(50),
  maker varchar(50),
  type varchar(50),
  CONSTRAINT product_pk PRIMARY KEY (model)
); 

table PC (
  serial_number varchar(50),
  model varchar(50),
  price number,
  speed number,
  ram number,
  hd varchar(50),
  cd varchar(50),
  CONSTRAINT pc_pk PRIMARY KEY (serial_number),CONSTRAINT pc_2_product_fkFOREIGN KEY (model) REFERENCES Product(model)
); 

Laptop (
  serial_number varchar(50),
  model varchar(50),
  price number,
  speed number,
  ram integer,
  hdvarchar(50),
  screen varchar(50),
  CONSTRAINT laptop_pk PRIMARY KEY (serial_number),CONSTRAINT laptop_2_product_fk FOREIGN KEY (model) REFERENCES Product(model)
);
```

And I need to find the cheapest pc or laptop considering speed, ram, hd. If you have any advice I'm gonna appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Please explain the rules you need to apply to consider a pc or laptop is cheaper than another one, and show what you've already done

Answer (score 0):

Use a WHERE clause to limit the results to those that qualify.  Then ORDER BY to have the cheapest first.  I'm not sure what you hd values are.  I will assume they are a size of some sort and can be compared to a single value.

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM PC
WHERE speed >= @speed_min AND ram >= @ram_min AND hd >= @hd_min
ORDER BY price ASC
```

If you need the cheapest laptop, do the same for Laptop.  If you need both, use a UNION ALL between the two queries.

Answer (score 0):

The direct option is rank each category and filter it.
1.First union all the PC and Laptop tables.
2. Assign rank/dense_rank to the data in the order of Price ASc and RAM desc.
3. If you sort rank you ll get the cheapest machine with highest config in order.

note : We usually decide the ram n processor before buying a laptop/PC so in real scenario decide what you want apply that in filter and rank rest of the information. You can also filter the price range and sort rest of the information as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all to take your time to answer, and I share the way who I answered it.

```
WITH rank AS(
   SELECT row_number() OVER ( 
    PARTITION BY ram,speed,hd   
    ORDER BY price) position, maker,serial_number,speed,ram,hd,price,type 
    FROM (SELECT serial_number,speed,ram,hd,price,p.type,p.maker FROM product p JOIN laptop l ON p.model = l.model  
    UNION ALL SELECT serial_number,speed,ram,hd,price,p.type,p.maker FROM product p JOIN pc ON p.model = pc.model) 
    ORDER BY price 
)
SELECT maker,serial_number,speed,ram,hd,price,type FROM rank WHERE price = (SELECT MIN(price) FROM rank);
```